# Airflow 2.3 - Dynamic Task Mapping using Operators

Tags: python, airflow

I've got a current implementation of some code which works fine, but only carries out a single check per dag run as I cannot feed through multiple results to downstream tasks. The new Airflow 2.3.0 dynamic task mapping seems to allow a set of tasks/operators to run with a list or dictionary of outputs from a previous task - https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/dynamic-task-mapping.html.

I have tried multiple different ways to utilise this but no success, below is my current working implementation. Note that it fetches 1 result:

```
default_args = {
    "owner": "test",
    "depends_on_past": False,
    "email_on_failure": False,
    "email_on_retry": False,
}

with DAG(
    "test",
    default_args=default_args,
    description="Test",
    template_searchpath=["/airflow_home/dags/"],
    start_date=datetime(2022, 5, 3),
    catchup=False,
    tags=["test"],
    render_template_as_native_obj=True,
) as dag:

    operator_a = CustomMySqlFetchDictionaryOperator(
        task_id="operator_a",
        mysql_conn_id="default_mysql",
        database_schema="test",
        sql="abc.sql",
        fetch_size=1,
        params={"param_1_value":"param_1_key",},
    )

    operator_b = CustomMySQLIntervalCheckOperator(
        task_id="operator_b",
        mysql_conn_id="default_mysql",
        database_schema="test",
        sql="abc.sql",
        days_back=1,
        date_filter_column="date",
        ratio_formula="max_over_min",
        metrics_thresholds={"AVG(total_size)": 1.05},
        ignore_zero=False,
        check_date="{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='operator_a')[0]['date'] }}",
        )

    operator_a >> operator_b
```

An example of what the first operator returns is shown below

```
[{'remote_path': 'data.txt', 
  'date': datetime.date(2022, 5, 2), 
  'last_modified': datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 3, 2, 47), 
  'total_size': 3291050}]
```

The check_date parameter in the second operator uses value 0 from the list as it can only return 1 result (due to fetch_size=1). As the dag parameter render_template_as_native_obj is set to True the dictionary is rendered correctly for the second operator and they both succeed.

However, when adapting this to use the new dynamic task mapping as shown below, I cannot get the second operator to use the values when the fetch_size is increased to >1 and the list now contains multiple dictionaries which I want to be mapped to multiple tasks for the same operator. Example of my attempt:

```
operator_b = CustomMySQLIntervalCheckOperator.partial(
    task_id="operator_b",
    mysql_conn_id="default_mysql",
    database_schema="test",
    sql="abc.sql",
    days_back=1,
    date_filter_column="date",
    ratio_formula="max_over_min",
    metrics_thresholds={"AVG(total_size)": 1.05},
    ignore_zero=False,
    ).expand(
    check_date="{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='operator_a')['date'] }}",
)
```

I have also tried to use XComArg via the **operator_a.output** notation (operator_a.output['date']) in the check_date parameter, however get an error when trying this "XComArg only supports str lookup, received int"

Appreciate any help or guidance I can get here!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`expand()` receives a `list` to operate the mapping on each element, but when you call `expend(check_date = " ")`, you are passing a `string`, right?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. In the expand() I am passing in `check_date="{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='operator_a')['date'] }}",` and this template would normally resolve to a date e.g. 2022-05-04 which I want to pass back as a string. The issue is I believe the templated XComArg dictionary that is being pulled is not being recognised as a list of dictionaries to iterate through. With the partial method, I would assume the list of dictionaries should get resolved to a dictionary where items can be called. Another key point is in my dag definition I have render_template_as_native_obj=True

Comment: I have a very similar code, which I pass a list that pulled from xcom to expand(), it first give me an error of
```expand() got an unexpected type 'str'```
I fixed by simply by adding a [ ], something like 
```expand( check_date= ["{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='operator_a')['date'] }}"])```
Can you test it and see if it works?

Comment: That does fix the unexpected 'str' error, but doesn't evaluate the template. Looking at the rendered template for the task, it displays as `('{{ '
 "ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='operator_a')['date'] "
 '}}')` in the 'rendered template' section of the task details

Comment: were you able to solve this problem? I am facing the same one